# Sexuality and first kissing and kissing questionnaire

Tags: data-request

I would like to know whether there is any honest histogram data on kissing and first experiences. The first question asks for one's perceived physical sexuality, and a separate histogram is generated for each case, so that, say, if someone checks Male, the total of all male-checked questionairres adds to100%. For example:

1)
I am / define myself as, physically

- [X] Male
- [ ] Female
- [X] Both

2)
On my first kiss,

- [X] She forced me into a kiss.
- [ ] I forced her into a kiss.

3)
In my opinion, the experience was

- [X] disgusting
- [ ] pleasant

4)
Because

- [X] It made me think of my mother kissing my father.
- [ ] It made me think of my father kissing my mother.

5)

- [X] I thought I was my father in it.
- [ ] I thought I was my mother in it.

6)

Nowadays, when I start kissing someone, I would rather think I am

- [ ] Male
- [X] Female

7)

Nowadays, when I kiss someone, my partner knows my answer to (6.)

- [X] Knows it.
- [ ] Doesn't know it.
- [X] Doesn't care.

8) On my first kiss, the thought of kissing

- [X] Scared the shit out of me.
- [ ] Was looking forward to it.

9) If I could plan my first kiss ahead, I would rather:

- [X] Impersonate the parent I liked the least (prior to separation if applicable).
- [ ] Impersonate the parent I like the most (duh).

10) When I kiss, the image of my mate,

- [X] quickly disassociates into that of another (perhaps separate) person
- [ ] It takes a while.

11) If my parents saw me do that, (if you don't invite the answer, check the ones you think what the answer could be):

My mother would feel uncomfortable.

- [X] Yes
- [ ] No
- [X] Maybe

My father would feel uncomfortable.

- [X] Yes
- [ ] No
- [X] Maybe

My mother would feel embarassed by the situation..

- [X] Yes
- [ ] No
- [X] Maybe

My father would feel embarrassed by the situation.

- [X] Yes
- [ ] No
- [X] Maybe

My mother would feel gealous of someone taking me away from them.

- [X] Yes
- [ ] No
- [X] Maybe

My father would feel gealous of someone taking me away from them.

- [X] Yes
- [ ] No
- [X] Maybe

My mother would feel envious of what she imagined her part in it.

- [X] Yes
- [ ] No
- [X] Maybe

My father would feel envious of what he imagined his part in it.

- [X] Yes
- [ ] No
- [X] Maybe

My mother would feel like cheating on my father, by copying.

- [X] Yes
- [ ] No
- [X] Maybe

My father would feel like cheating on my mother, by copying.

- [X] Yes
- [ ] No
- [X] Maybe

Thank you for letting me know where I can find a questionnaire of this sort.

Comment: Did you create these questions or did they come from an existing survey/study?

Comment: probably the best you'll do in a public use data set is http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/data/nsfg/nsfg_2011-2013_app1a_femrespfile_index_v2.pdf  (search for `age at first`) and then code to analyze it here  https://github.com/ajdamico/asdfree/tree/master/National%20Survey%20of%20Family%20Growth

Comment: You should note (q1,q6) that some people, regard themselves to be neither male or female, not both.